# How to know all the Connected devices to my Access Point including Phones

Tags: network, wifi, network-scanners

I need to list all the connected devices in my AP wireless network including mobile phones, also if it possible to know more information about each device, I am using Windows 7 and my access point is TP-Link

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find that in the admin console for the AP. It should list them by MAC, IP address, and Hostname if the device has one.

Comment: Then I suppose, you could also analyze MAC addresses to find the manufacturer and consequently the type of the device connected.